# iteritems does not return all dictionary items

Tags: python, django

I'm iterating over a dictionary using iteritems() to create objects in Django. However, I found that the number of created objects is not the same of number of the dictionary objects.

On exploring this further, I discovered that the dictionary's iteritems() method is only returning 197 tuples, while the dictionary itself contains 269 items.

```
data = {...}
print len(data) #output: 269
for k, v in data.iteritems():
    Category.objects.create(name=k).save()
len(Category.objects.all()) #output: 197
```

Model definition:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: You don't need to `.save()` after `.create()`, it saves it for you.

Comment: Can you print the `Category` model class?

Comment: How do you check the number of created objects? Please, print the actual code, including the definition of your model. Also, note, that you don't need to call `.save()` if you use `.create()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't recommend you use `len(Category.objects.all())` to count objects. Instead, you should use

```
Category.objects.count()
```

It's not a matter of style, but efficiency. The latter uses SQL COUNT, so the number of objects is calculated not by python but by your database (mysql, sqlite, etc.)

I cannot comment on why you're getting 192 objects, not 267. My guess is it's because your `create` function is getting some unusable parameters - maybe `k` is not a string, or maybe its length exceeds 100 characters.

Can you investigate which elements didn't save and provide this information?

Comment: According to OP's updates, the issue seems to be with `data.iteritems()`, not `Category.objects.create()`